# Fourier synthesis of 3d medical imagiing

Tags: python, numpy, image-processing, signal-processing, fft

I am trying to generate 3-dimensional image. Using optimization - where wave frequencies and amplitudes will be learned. Hence given a set of frequencies, amplitudes and shifts I would like to create 3d image by adding a series of 3D gratings.

I based my approach on a blog post by Stephen Gruppetta [1].

However, as the original code was for 2D images - I do not know exactly how to adapt it to 3D. Below is what I tried - but I am nearly certain that something is wrong as I suppose that for the 3D case, I should have 2 angles defined not one.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x = np.arange(-7, 7, 1)
X, Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x, x,x)
wavelength = 5
angle = np.pi*1.5
grating = np.sin(
    2*np.pi*(X*np.cos(angle) + Y*np.sin(angle)+Z*np.cos(angle)) / wavelength
)
plt.set_cmap("gray")
plt.imshow(grating[:,:,1])
plt.show()
```

Additionally, I am wondering what possible wavelengths will lead to visible differences for a given image size. I did some experimentation and it seems that wavelength between 0.1 and 2 times the image width (in the example above 15 - the width of meshgrid) is sensible - but I did it only by experimentation - is there some mathematical way to calculate it?

1)https://thepythoncodingbook.com/2021/08/30/2d-fourier-transform-in-python-and-fourier-synthesis-of-images/

Comment: You want to generate 3d scalar field, right? I think "3d image" term is used to depict 2d image that seems to have depth (3rd dimension).

Comment: 3d medical image like MRI 

Comment: Yes, you need two angles. Regarding wavelengths, look at the DFT. It decomposes the image into some waves with integer frequencies k from 0 to N-1 pixels (N is the width of the image); half of those alias to the other half. So the meaningful frequencies k are 0 to N/2 (inclusive). These correspond to periods T=N/k of 2 pixels to N pixels, plus a constant component.

Comment: Thanks @CrisLuengo I get about range, Hovewer how to apply the second angle ? Here we have X times cos and Y times Sin first angle , how to apply second angle ?

Comment: why even deal with angles? that's just a headache. don't do that. -- the fourier transform gives you an array with a magnitude and the wavelengths along each dimension, for each magnitude (usually X and Y). just run through those coefficients starting from the "center" (DC coefficient) in whatever fashion you like, say in a square spiral (manhattan distance) or circle (euclidean distance). just find the closest element that hasn't been marked as "done".

Comment: Thanks @ChristophRackwitz  , however idea here is to describe the texture with added some stochasticity using small number of descriptors,  on irregular domain - simple fft of the texture in such irregular domain would have problems, also I want to have short token with couple waves that could be put with other tokens as transformer, it is hard to select biggest coefficients from normal fourier in a differentiable manner as sort is not differentiable, and if I would get all fourier coefficients  to a token it would be simply to large

Comment: Although @ChristophRackwitz maybe I  do not understand fully idea, if I would collapse just a center of fourier transformed image to token it may be indeed good idea as most important tokens particularly in fftshift should be in a center, problem with irregularity, as if learned I generate then mask and compare, here I need rectangular domain for fft

Comment: What Christoph is saying is that instead of a magnitude and two angles, which together define a 3D vector, you can represent that exact same vector using its three Cartesian components. That makes it easier to create a sine wave.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I have the answer now - If anybody has some thoughts on it please comment

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def get_3d_grating_to_scan(wavelength, alphaa,betaa,amplitude,shift_x,shift_y,shift_z, shift_amplitude,X,Y,Z):
        alpha = np.pi*alphaa
        beta = np.pi*betaa
        grating = (np.sin(
        2*np.pi*(((X*np.cos(alpha)*np.cos(beta))+shift_x) + (Y*np.sin(alpha)*np.cos(beta)+shift_y) +(Z*np.sin(beta)) +shift_z)/ wavelength
          )*amplitude)+shift_amplitude
        return grating


x = np.arange(-70, 70, 1)
X,Y,Z = np.meshgrid(x, x,x)
wavelength = 50
amplitude=1
# shift_x=50
# shift_y=50
# shift_z=50

shift_x=0
shift_y=0
shift_z=0

shift_amplitude=0
alpha = 1.7
beta =1.7
grating=get_3d_grating_to_scan(wavelength, alpha,beta,amplitude,shift_x,shift_y,shift_z, shift_amplitude,X,Y,Z)

plt.set_cmap("gray")
plt.imshow(np.array(grating)[:,5,:])
plt.show()
```